# Railsのファイルの変更の自動読み込みについて

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

RubyonRailsを使っていてCSSやviewなどを変更した後にサーバーを再起動しなくても
自動で変更を読み込んでくれます.

しかし, Gemfileにgemを新規に追加して`bundle install`した時には手動でサーバーを再起動しないと読み込んでくれません.
Railsはどのようなファイルまでを自動で読み込んでくれるのでしょうか.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なかなか興味深い質問ですね。
長年Railsをやっていると感覚的に「この変更は再起動が必要」というルールがつかめてきますが、正確な仕様はちゃんと考えたことがありませんでした。

英語でググってみたところ、同じようなQ&Aを見つけました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729345/when-do-i-need-to-restart-server-in-rails

ここの回答を引用するなら

> `app/`以下のファイルと`config/routes.rb`の変更は再起動が不要、それ以外は再起動が必要

ということになります。

なるほど、確かにそう言われてみればそうかもしれません。

もうちょっと厳密に言うと、「データベーステーブルの変更（migrationの実行）や`public`以下、`vender/assets`以下のファイルの変更も再起動が不要」と言えそうです。

とはいえ、「`app/`以下のファイルと`config/routes.rb`の変更は再起動が不要」はシンプルで覚えやすいので、まずはこれを原則として覚えておけば困ることはほとんどなさそうです。