# gem追加時にSprockets::FileNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

gem追加時に毎回このエラーが出て便利なgemを使用することに阻まれます。
今回は、jquery-mobile-railsを入れようとしました。
mmenuを追加しようとした時も、同様のエラーが出ます。

```
Sporckets::FileNotFound in Article#index
couldn't find file 'jquery.mobile' with type text/css
```

sp/application.css

```
*
*= require jquery.mobile
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

application.html+sp.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'sp/application', media: 'all',  'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'sp/application' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery_mobile_rails'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
    jquery_mobile_rails (1.4.5)
```

これを追加したうえで、jqueryのファイルを落としてきてパス指定をhtml+sp.erbに書く必要があるのでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Gemfileにgemを追加する前にRailsを立ち上げた場合、gem追加後に再起動しないと追加したgemが読み込まれず`Sprockets::FileNotFound`が出てしまうと思います。

gemを追加したあと、`Sprockets::FileNotFound`が出た場合、Railsを再起動してみてはいかがでしょうか?

以前にも似たような質問があったので参考になれば。

[ruby - Railsのファイルの変更の自動読み込みについて - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/8228/rails%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%AE%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)